# Upgrade to Micronaut 3.0 failed for Http Client (ClassNotFoundException AsyncSSLPrivateKeyMethod)

Tags: migration, micronaut

i upgraded to Micronaut 3.0 according to https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/#upgrading by adding all the rxjava2 depdendencies.

```
implementation("io.micronaut.rxjava2:micronaut-rxjava2")
implementation("io.micronaut.rxjava2:micronaut-rxjava2-http-client")
implementation("io.micronaut.rxjava2:micronaut-rxjava2-http-server-netty")
```

While having a MicronautTest using a RxHttpClient i get a ClassNotFoundException

```
Error instantiating bean of type  [de.bitzer.iot.alarmservice.status.AlarmStatusTest]

Message: io/netty/internal/tcnative/AsyncSSLPrivateKeyMethod
Path Taken: AlarmStatusTest.client
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Error instantiating bean of type  [de.bitzer.iot.alarmservice.status.AlarmStatusTest]

Message: io/netty/internal/tcnative/AsyncSSLPrivateKeyMethod
Path Taken: AlarmStatusTest.client
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2265)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getScopedBeanForDefinition(DefaultBeanContext.java:2834)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanForDefinition(DefaultBeanContext.java:2725)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2685)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1555)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.resolveBean(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:1561)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.resolveBean(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:1549)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.getBeanForField(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:1259)
    at de.bitzer.iot.alarmservice.status.$AlarmStatusTest$Definition.injectBean(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.inject(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:559)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doInject(DefaultBeanContext.java:2533)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.inject(DefaultBeanContext.java:925)
    at io.micronaut.test.extensions.AbstractMicronautExtension.beforeEach(AbstractMicronautExtension.java:307)
    at io.micronaut.test.extensions.junit5.MicronautJunit5Extension.beforeEach(MicronautJunit5Extension.java:119)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeEachCallbacks$1(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:159)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs$5(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:195)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:195)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeEachCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:158)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:125)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy5.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:135)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/internal/tcnative/AsyncSSLPrivateKeyMethod
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.newClientContextInternal(SslContext.java:830)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder.build(SslContextBuilder.java:611)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.netty.ssl.NettyClientSslBuilder.build(NettyClientSslBuilder.java:107)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient.<init>(DefaultHttpClient.java:326)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.netty.DefaultNettyHttpClientRegistry.buildClient(DefaultNettyHttpClientRegistry.java:436)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.netty.DefaultNettyHttpClientRegistry.lambda$getClient$1(DefaultNettyHttpClientRegistry.java:346)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.netty.DefaultNettyHttpClientRegistry.getClient(DefaultNettyHttpClientRegistry.java:292)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.netty.DefaultNettyHttpClientRegistry.getClient(DefaultNettyHttpClientRegistry.java:174)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.netty.DefaultNettyHttpClientRegistry.resolveDefaultHttpClient(DefaultNettyHttpClientRegistry.java:485)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.netty.DefaultNettyHttpClientRegistry.resolveStreamingHttpClient(DefaultNettyHttpClientRegistry.java:279)
    at io.micronaut.rxjava2.http.client.RxStreamingHttpClientFactory.streamingHttpClient(RxStreamingHttpClientFactory.java:63)
    at io.micronaut.rxjava2.http.client.$RxStreamingHttpClientFactory$StreamingHttpClient0$Definition.doBuild(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.build(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:707)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2225)
    ... 87 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.netty.internal.tcnative.AsyncSSLPrivateKeyMethod
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
    ... 102 more
```

I checked the dependencies several times and also changed the imports to the correct ones.
But still fails.
Have no idea, where to look at. Maybe someone could help me.

Regards
Oliver

Comment: could you show the dependencies section from build.gradle or pom.xml?

Comment: was a little more complex, the build.gradle was fine, it comes around 3 corners from a lib which uses azure-storage-blob which provides also a netty dependency... but thx for the reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue. Came in that particular case by

`implementation('com.azure:azure-storage-blob:12.13.0')`

Which has a netty depdendency.

My workaround was to manually add the tcnative dependency

`implementation 'io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:2.0.41.Final'`